# RestAPI call with Basic Authentication

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, basic-authentication

I am trying to do a Rest API call with basic authentication. I am able to make the call successfully, but the issue is that if I give wrong username & password in the call, then also I am getting success in response.

I tried by making the login & password field as blank still the success response is received. I believe its a caching issue. The code that I am trying is as follows

```
@IBAction func sampleButtonAction()
    {
        let headers = [
            "cache-control": "no-cache"
        ]
        let login = "XXXXX"
        let password = "XXXXX"
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: "https://Sample.com")! as URL,
                                          cachePolicy: .reloadIgnoringLocalCacheData,
                                          timeoutInterval: 10.0)
        request.httpMethod = "GET"
        request.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers

        let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        let loginData = String(format: "%@:%@", login, password).data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!
        let base64EncodedCredential = loginData.base64EncodedString()
        let authString = "Basic \(base64EncodedCredential)"
        config.httpAdditionalHeaders = ["Authorization" : authString]

        let session = URLSession.shared
        let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
            if (error != nil) {
                print(error!)
            } else {
                let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse
                print(httpResponse!)
                let responseData = String(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
                print(responseData!)
            }
        })
        dataTask.resume()
    }
```

Can someone point out what I am doing wrong?. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please explain what exactly goes wrong. "I am not able to implement it successfully" is very vague.

Comment: @Koen Updated my post with response that i am getting

Comment: The server response isn't really relevant for the Swift portion. What you need to do is log the request on the server and see if the authentication header is properly set up. If that is ok, then it must be some problem a the server side.

Comment: @Koen and @ Rengers The question has been updated

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you mean that `error` is still `nil` in the callback, even when the HTTP status code is outside 2xx.

That is expected behaviour. The error variable is only non `nil` when the actual network request failed, for example when there is no internet connection. When the request succeeds, it wil be nil regardless of the response HTTP code.

So what you need to do is expand your logic to include a check on the response status code:

```
if (200 ... 299).contains(httpResponse.statusCode!)
```